# Wso2 esb: Edit the response of one rest API and send that response to another rest api

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We have 2 rest APIs and have to edit and send the one rest API response as a request message to the another rest API.

Ex: First api response is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api>
  <attribute_set_id>4</attribute_set_id>
  <type_id>simple</type_id>
  <sku>test_dress</sku>
</api>
```

Now we have to edit that response as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api>
  <id>4</id>
  <product_id>simple</product_id>
  <sku>test_dress</sku>
</api>
```

and send that response as a request message to the another rest api.
Is it possible through WSO2 ESB and please provide any sample to work for above scenario.

Please let me know if I need to give more details.

Thanks,
Geetha Gupta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little sample you must customize to meet your needs :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="MyProxy"
       transports="http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
    <description/>
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <!-- send current message to rest api 1 (sample with a dynamic value inside rest url) -->
            <property name="uri.var.MyPath" value="mypath"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="POST" uri-template="http://myhost/{uri.var.MyPath}/restapi1"/>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <!-- here come the response from rest api 1 : transform this response -->
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <api>
                        <id>$1</id>
                        <product_id>$2</product_id>
                        <sku>$3</sku>
                    </api>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//api/attribute_set_id/text()"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//api/type_id/text()"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//api/sku/text()"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <!-- call rest api 2 -->
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="POST" uri-template="http://myhost/{uri.var.MyPath}/restapi2"/>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <!-- send back response from restapi2 -->
            <send/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

Comment: If the first API response has multiple product details how can I get the arguments for each product and send to second API Request.       <api>
<product>
  <attribute_set_id>4</attribute_set_id>
  <type_id>simple</type_id>
  <sku>test_dress</sku>
  </product>
  <product>
  <attribute_set_id>5</attribute_set_id>
  <type_id>simple</type_id>
  <sku>test_material</sku>
  </product>
</api>

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the XSLT mediator (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB460/XSLT+Mediator).

Refer http://architects.dzone.com/articles/xslt-mediator-tutorial for an example for this.

Comment: I want to edit the response before sending to the second rest api as <attribute_set_id> to <id> and <type_id> to  <product_id>

Comment: Sorry for the above. You should use Payload Factory Mediator for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can  do it through  following steps

- Read  response and assign  the response parameters to some variables by using `<proprty>`
- Set dynamic payload with these parameters by using     `<payloadFactory>`
- After you can call another rest using `<send>` mediator